# Ternary operator applies class-expanding macro to the both of operands

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, macros, ternary-operator

I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and Windows 7.

I have the `DataDecoder` class to decode some data. Here it is:

```
template< typename T >
class DataDecoder
{

private:

    T lpData;

public:

    DataDecoder() { lpData = NULL; }
    DataDecoder( T lpSource ) { lpData = (T)DecodeStaticData(lpSource); }
    ~DataDecoder() { if(lpData) free(lpData); }
    operator T() { return lpData; }
};
```

This class works perfectly. Also I have this macro:

```
#define _STR_A(x) DataDecoder<char*>(x)
```

It works perfectly too. But there is another construction in my code:

```
LPVOID lpAdditionalData = NULL;
LPSTR lpTemp = lpAdditionalData ? _STR_A("SOMEDATA") : NULL;
```

At this point weird things begin to happen. First of all I get NULL parameter in my `DecodeStaticData()`. But it could not be true: `_STR_A()` applies to valid parameter only. Then I decided to look at disassembly:

```
0011843A  cmp         dword ptr [lpAdditionalData],0  
00118441  je          WinMain+172h (118462h)  
00118443  push        offset string "SOMEDATA" (124068h)  
00118448  lea         ecx,[ebp-0C2Ch]  
0011844E  call        DataDecoder<char *>::DataDecoder<char *> (117770h)  
00118453  or          dword ptr [ebp-0C14h],1  
0011845A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0C34h],eax  
00118460  jmp         WinMain+18Ch (11847Ch)  
00118462  push        0  
00118464  lea         ecx,[ebp-0C28h]  
0011846A  call        DataDecoder<char *>::DataDecoder<char *> (117770h)
```

As you can see, class constructor is called in BOTH cases, for "SOMEDATA" and for NULL too!

Is it correct behavior? How can I deal with this?

**UPDATE:** I turned on preprocessing to file and this is what I see:

```
LPSTR lpTemp = lpAdditionalData ? DataDecoder<char*>("SOMEDATA") : 0;
```

So, it is not preprocessor problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any expression, one involving a conditional operator must have a type. An expression `c ? a : b` can't magically have a type that changes at run-time depending on the value of `c` - the type of `a` sometimes, the type of `b` other times. Instead, if `a` and `b` are of different types, there are complicated rules that determine the final type of the overall expression, by trying to coerce one to the type of the other.

In your case, `DataDecoder<char*>(x)` can't be coerced to the type of `NULL`, but `NULL` can be coerced to `DataDecoder<char*>`, by way of a user-defined conversion `DataDecoder<char*>(NULL)`. This is what you observe.

Comment: Thanks, right you are. I casted `DataDecoder<char*>` to `(char*)` and problem is solved now.